# Angular JS : Can two different pages have same ng-app and ng-controller?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, ng-controller

I am building few web pages where I have to show the content with the help of angular .

**Problem** : The links that take my page to some other page is not loading the page it just changes the URL but not the content of the page .

I believe it is happening because I am using **same ng-app and ng-controller** on all the pages .

I am doing so because I want to use same angular script js on all pages (i.e centralized.)

On all the Pages it uses same ajax call with different parameters (as per the requirement.)

Is there any way out so that I can keep my angular script centralized and the problem is also solved.

Thanks

Comment: Where and How are you using `ngApp` directive? Share the code

Comment: I am using it as :<html lang="en" ng-app="angularTable">
on all pages
Also, if I refresh the page it takes me to the desired page (as URL is already changed )

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is actually SPA(Single page app). It has one page with different views. So use routing concept of angularJS to switch the views. You need not to give two different ng-app names or controller names. Each view will have its own controller. (check [AngularJS SPA Concept](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/808213/Developing-a-Large-Scale-Application-with-a-Single))

Below example might help you.

**Index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-$route-service-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  

  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngRouteExample">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
  Choose:
  <a href="Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
  <a href="Book/Moby/ch/1">Moby: Ch1</a> |
  <a href="Book/Gatsby">Gatsby</a> |
  <a href="Book/Gatsby/ch/4?key=value">Gatsby: Ch4</a> |
  <a href="Book/Scarlet">Scarlet Letter</a><br/>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <hr />

  <pre>$location.path() = {{$location.path()}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.templateUrl = {{$route.current.templateUrl}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.params = {{$route.current.params}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.scope.name = {{$route.current.scope.name}}</pre>
  <pre>$routeParams = {{$routeParams}}</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**book.html**

```html
controller: {{name}}<br />
Book Id: {{params.bookId}}<br />
```

**chapter.html**

```html
controller: {{name}}<br />
Book Id: {{params.bookId}}<br />
Chapter Id: {{params.chapterId}}
```

**script.js**

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngRouteExample', ['ngRoute'])

 .controller('MainController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
     $scope.$route = $route;
     $scope.$location = $location;
     $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
 })

 .controller('BookController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
     $scope.name = "BookController";
     $scope.params = $routeParams;
 })

 .controller('ChapterController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
     $scope.name = "ChapterController";
     $scope.params = $routeParams;
 })

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/Book/:bookId', {
    templateUrl: 'book.html',
    controller: 'BookController',
    resolve: {
      // I will cause a 1 second delay
      delay: function($q, $timeout) {
        var delay = $q.defer();
        $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
        return delay.promise;
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
    templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
    controller: 'ChapterController'
  });

  // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
})(window.angular);
```

We can explore the exact solution if you post your code.